# A basis in the space of all tempered distributions over $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, distribution-theory, schauder-basis

What is a(n uncountable) basis in the topological vector space $\mathcal{S}' \left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$ ? How can any tempered distribution be expanded in terms of such a basis?

Comment: Any compactly supported distribution is of the form $\sum_{|\alpha|\le N}\partial_\alpha f_\alpha$ with $f_\alpha$ continuous. Also $e^{-\pi  |x|^2/k^2} ( T \ast k^n e^{-\pi k^2 |x|^2}) \in S$ and $\to T$.

Answer (score 2):

You said "uncountable" which suggests you are talking about a Hamel basis (only allowed finite linear combinations to get all vectors). This is a useless notion in the present context. What you might need rather is a Schauder basis (where you are allowed infinite sums, with suitable notion of convergence). There is a countable Schauder basis given by Hermite functions. See [this article](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1665472) by B. Simon.